# Fail to install Rcpp, get many errors

Tags: r, rcpp

Tried to install Rcpp with `install.packages("Rcpp")`, but it fails. Following is part of the errors. I can not understand them. I am not familiar with R or cpp, even I use `rpy` to call R functions.

PS: MacOS10, R4.1.0

```
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs clang++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c api.cpp -o api.o In file included from api.cpp:26: In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27: In file included from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:30: In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:66: In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:321:9: error:
      no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace using ::signbit;
      ~~^ /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:322:9: error:
      no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace using ::fpclassify;
      ~~^ /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:323:9: error:
      no member named 'isfinite' in the global namespace; did you mean 'finite'? using ::isfinite;
      ~~^ /usr/local/include/c++/v1/math.h:752:12: note: 'finite' ... /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:324:9: error:
      no member named 'isinf' in the global namespace using ::isinf;
      ~~^ /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:325:9: error: ... ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27: In file included from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:30: In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:66: In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:644:26: error:
      no template named 'numeric_limits'
    bool _FloatBigger = (numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits > numeric_limit...
                         ^ /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:644:60: error: ...
    int _Bits = (numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits - numeric_limits<_FloatT>...
                                                 ^  incorre...
                ^ fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=] 20 errors generated. make: *** [api.o] Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.1/site-library/Rcpp’
```

Comment: Do you have `xcode` installed? Do these instructions help - https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/020_install.html ?

Comment: @Onyambu The OP says they are on MacOS

Comment: Hm, we have countless users on macOS (though I am not one of them) so is odd. Can you show the output of `sessionInfo()` ? Also, can you try a binary installation of `Rcpp` -- and why does it not default to that?  For harder macOS questions, also consder the r-sig-mac mailing list.

Comment: Hm, `/usr/local/Cellar/r` -- where did you install R from?  You should follow [these official instructions](https://mac.r-project.org/).